# submit to a spring controller from a javascript code

Tags: javascript, java, html, spring

I am trying to submit a form to a controller from a javascript but the form button is not showing.

This is my attempt

```
 for (var i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {
                        users += '<strong>' + json[i].email + '</strong><br/>'  + '<br/>' + json[i].tok + '<hr><br/>';


                        //trying to hit to the controller from here but it is not working
                        //trying to hit to the controller from here but it is not working
                '<form method="post" action="searchAdmin" novalidate="novalidate">'
                '<input type="email" value="json[i].email" name="searchName" id="searchName"/>'
                 //on clicking the fetch button let it submit to the controller
                 '<input type="submit" value="FETCH" />'
                 '</form>'
```

Kindly assist!

Comment: the input - closing tag seems to be missing

Comment: I added it but still the same. Even on inspecting element, the form does not show

Comment: This question basically has nothing to do with Spring at this moment.

Comment: Is the deployed code up-to-date?

Comment: Yes. the deployed code is up to date

Comment: try changing the "button" to "input" and maybe post the resulting raw html

Comment: Have done that and shown the resulting html

Comment: I meant the html that lands in your browser (if you right click in the browser there should be an option "show source" or something)

Comment: post the html source that is generated.

Comment: Had shown the picture of the html source that is generated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
user+='<form met....
```

because you have used `;` on the first line so you need to append this string

Comment: please how do I retrieve the raw value  value="json[i].email"

Comment: Yes. I have appended it but it is not returning the actual value of value="json[i].email"

Comment: @Francis the button is visible now?

Comment: Yes it is but its not its not treating this json[i].email as a value

Comment: alert it and see if there is some value or not..if there is the value then do it liek this `value="'+json[i].email+'"`

Answer (score 0):

Could you try making the form a single string? Try like below;

```
//trying to hit to the controller from here but it is not working
                    '<form method="post" action="searchAdmin" novalidate="novalidate"><input type="email" value="json[i].email" name="searchName" id="searchName"/><button type="submit">FETCH</button></form>'
```